# Grab the video ID only from youtube's URLs

Tags: php, youtube, explode

How can I grab the video ID only from the youtube's URLs?

For instance,

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPm3QVKlBJg

sometime the URLs contain other information after the 'v' like

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z29MkJdMKqs&feature=grec_index

but I don't want the other info, just video ID.

I only can think of using explode,

```
$url  = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPm3QVKlBJg";
$pieces = explode("v=", $url);
```

but how to clean up the URLs like this?

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z29MkJdMKqs&feature=grec_index

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse youtube video id using preg_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match)

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate unless you assume the user was after a regex solution, which is *not* the best solution to this problem.

Comment: @meagar but that question also had a `parse_url` solution by Gumbo, so it'll work as a duplicate.

Comment: @Pekka They're asking different questions. The regex solution was accepted as correct in the other question, seemingly indicating it really was about a regex, not about the *best* method of finding the video id.

Comment: @meagar true, that's a point. The same happened to my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737634/ But now we have one whose accepted answer is actually the correct one. Yay! :)

Comment: yes the answer from the other thread is not what I am looking for. thanks guys! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never use regular expressions when the same thing can be accomplished through purpose-built functions.

You can use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break the URL up into its segments, and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to break the query string portion into a key/value array:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z29MkJdMKqs&feature=grec_index'

// break the URL into its components
$parts = parse_url($url);

// $parts['query'] contains the query string: 'v=Z29MkJdMKqs&feature=grec_index'

// parse variables into key=>value array
$query = array();
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

echo $query['v']; // Z29MkJdMKqs
echo $query['feature'] // grec_index
```

The alternate form of `parse_str` extracts variables into the current scope. You could build this into a function to find and return the `v` parameter:

```
// Returns null if video id doesn't exist in URL
function get_video_id($url) {
  $parts = parse_url($url);

  // Make sure $url had a query string
  if (!array_key_exists('query', $parts))
    return null;

  parse_str($parts['query']);

  // Return the 'v' parameter if it existed
  return isset($v) ? $v : null;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that YouTube URLs are inconsistent to say the least.  There are at least 10 different URL formats that YouTube will accept and only a few of them use the ?v= format for submitting the video ID.  Most URL formats contain the video ID as part of the URLs path as follows: `http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ`