# Replace text with php using str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parse youtube video id using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match)
>   [Grab the video ID only from youtube's URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045154/grab-the-video-id-only-from-youtubes-urls)

I use something like this now but i get a lot of errors...

```
$video_id = $_GET['url'];

$video_id = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=related','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=fvwrel','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&hd=1','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=relmfu','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=channel_video_title','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=list_related','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('&playnext=1','',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('_player','',$video_id);
```

The problem is that youtube has multiple url variables for '&feature=' and maybe others

The only thing i want to extract from the youtube url is the unique video id

ex: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=**lgT1AidzRWM**&feature=related

and nothing after the id or before

can someone help me to get it?

Comment: @mario This question asks to use string replacement, not regex.

Comment: @mc10 Only because he doesn't realize there's a safer way to go..

Comment: @mario you do **not** need to use `preg_match`.... (see my answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgT1AidzRWM&feature=related";
$p_url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($p_url['query'], $p_param);
print_r($p_param['v']);
```

Example: http://codepad.org/BiWKxfSZ

Comment: wow! that was fast! really this was what i was looking for. i am sorry I have not thought about it.

Comment: @m3tsys your welcome ^_^

Answer (score 3):

```
$video_id = parse_url($video_id);    
parse_str($video_id['query'], $video_id);
echo $video_id['v'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions

```
preg_match("/v=(\w+)/", $video_id, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better of using a regular expression for this.
Untested:

```
if(preg_match('/[\?&]v=([^&]*?)/', $video_id, $match))
{
    $video_id = $match[1];
}
else exit('video id not found');
```

Answer (score 0):

using preg_match would be the most efficient way for this you can search the string for watch?v= up to the & or special char and place that into a variable.

this should help

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php